# How to Change Flutter repository URL in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

download.flutter.io is blocked at my company network, How can i switch the repository to something like https://dart-pub.mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/ ?.
I am using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can export `FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL` and `PUB_HOSTED_URL` in the terminal, and run `flutter pub get` to fetch the dependencies. Then you should be able to develop in Android Studio.

Currently, I haven't found a way to configure the flutter plugin of Android Studio to fetch packages from mirrors. There is a setting for the terminal, but that does not affect how the flutter plugin works.

Also, setting HTTP proxy doesn't work for the flutter plugin, either.